# Magento 1.7 WYSIWYG editor not populating storage root

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I have a 1.7 Magento installation.  In the WYSIWYG blog post editor, the storage root doesn't populate.  Images in the root folder do show up in the file window,  and if you create a folder through the interface, it shows up in the tree and is even created on the disk, but if you reload the page and go back to the editor, it disappears.

Any ideas on what this could be?  I've tried other suggestions from forum posts about commenting out code in Storage.php,  but that didn't help

Answer (score 1):

Go to:

```
app/code/core/Mage/Cms/Model/Wysiwyg/
```

edit the **Config.php** and change

```
const IMAGE_DIRECTORY = 'wysiwyg';
```

to

```
const IMAGE_DIRECTORY = '.';
```